# Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8 vb .net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excepciones

Al querer leer de la base de datos con `vb.net` me marca una `exception`, al parecer porque estoy trayendo datos `NULL`. Soy nuevo en sql server, este es mi código espero me puedan ayudar.

Guarde los datos de una huella dactilar en sql server pero ahora al intentar traerlos marca la excepcion los datos son guardados en varbinary, el campo donde estan guardados es "fp" y al querer compararlos es cuando me manda el error.

```
Public Sub OnComplete(Capture As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, Sample As Sample) Implements EventHandler.OnComplete

        ponerImagen(ConvertirSampleaMapadeBits(Sample))

Dim caracteristicas As DPFP.FeatureSet = extraerCaracteristicas(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)

        If Not caracteristicas Is Nothing Then
            Dim result As New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
            Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection(connectionString:=My.Settings.cnn)
            sqlCon.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cre_fp"
            Dim read As SqlDataReader
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim verificado As Boolean = False
            Dim cuenta As String = ""
            While (read.Read())
                Dim memoria As New MemoryStream(CType(read("fp"), Byte()))
                template.DeSerialize(memoria.ToArray())
                verificador.Verify(caracteristicas, template, result)
                If (result.Verified) Then
                    cuenta = ("cuenta")
                    verificado = True
                   Exit While
                End If
            End While
            If (verificado) Then
                MessageBox.Show(cuenta)
            Else

       MessageBox.Show("No se ha encontrado al cliente en la base de datos")
            End If
            read.Dispose()
            cmd.Dispose()
            sqlCon.Close()
            sqlCon.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Debe validar que el valor de `fp` no sea NULL. ¿Qué tipo de dato es `fp`, por cierto?. Te recomiendo investigar o [edit] tu pregunta con lo que hayas intentado. Creo que un ejemplo de qué datos está trayendo esa consulta y la estructura de la tabla `cre_fp` ayudará a que otros te comprendan mejor tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: el valor de fp es varbinary, estoy tratando de traer los datos de una huella dactilar.

Creo que si no especifique correctamente, deja la planteo de nuevo

Comment: Es probable que el tipo de dato *(o al tamaño)* no sean los adecuados para guardar la información. Mire este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743881/4092887) o busque `HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8` en Google. Le recomiendo usar `try/catch` para capturar el mensaje de la excepción completa: Ejemplo: `try { /* Put your code here*/ } catch (Exception ex) { string strError = ex.ToString(); }`.

Comment: Ya los cambie pero sigue fallando, cree una nueva tabla con solo 2 valores cuenta (de tipo Char) y fp (varbinary(MAX)) y si los registro en la vieja tabla tiene 6 

cuenta
cliente
dedo
empleado
fecha
fp

pero en esa no puedo llamar los datos

Comment: Al final fue un problema con la base datos, los archivos que estaba mandando guardar estaban en img y una version anterior, al querer actualizar a varbinary tuvo un problema, la unica solucion fue crear una tabla nueva y insertar los datos de la antigua (un poco perdida pero funciono :/)